# Firebase authentication & Public / Private Routing - React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my react application, I am trying to implement Public and Private routes with `react-router-dom`.

I am currently getting the authentication state from `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` function.

The problem is that since the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` function is asynchronous, JSX block is rendered with `authState` of `false` first, and then `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` sets `authState` to `true` after the JSX is returned.

So, the authentication is true, but my react app stays at the sign-in page.

PublicRoute.js

```
const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, restricted, ...rest }) => {

    let authState = false;

    getAuthState()
        .then(user => {
            if (user.uid) {
                authState = true;
            } else {
                authState = false;
        }
    })

    return (
        <Route { ...rest } render={ props => (
            authState && restricted
                ? <Redirect to="/" />
                : <Component { ...props } />
        ) } />
    )
};

export default PublicRoute;
```

getAuthState.js

```
export const getAuthState = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const waitAuthStateChange = () => {
            let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

            if (currentUser === null) {
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => currentUser = user);
                setTimeout(waitAuthStateChange, 100);

            } else {
                resolve(currentUser);

            }
        }

        waitAuthStateChange();
    })
};
```

I don't know how to make re-render or re-return the JSX after the authentication is fetched by `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` listener.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a `React state`.

To use it, you can use it with a hook called useState();

Example,

```
const [authState,setAuthState] = useState(false);

getAuthState()
        .then(user => {
            if (user.uid) {
                setAuthState(true);
            }
    })
```

Your current `authState` is a normal javascript object, so React doesn't regard it as a change and therefore, won't re-render.

Change it to React state and then when you do a `setAuthState()` , React use it as a pivot for change and will render again.

Side Note: Calling getAuthState() by itself is not a good practice in React.
In React way, it should be put inside the useEffect() hook.

- Reference for useState: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- Reference for useEffect: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 

I've tried to make `authState` as a state variable. However, when I did that, I ended up getting another error that says "SecurityError: Attempt to use history.replaceState() more than 100 times per 30 seconds" 

How can I deal with this one?

Comment: thats a router issue. probably because of `Redirect`, what are at the top of your router. please show me what `<Route>` come right after `<Router><Switch>...</Switch></Router>` ...or try to change Redirect into `<Redirect to="/login" />` or smth instead of "/"